# Typescript: Constructor field lacks a construct signature

Tags: typescript, constructor

Why doesn't the `constructor` field of an object doesn't have a construct signature?

```
class X {
}

const x = new X
// disallowed:
// const y = new x.constructor
// cast to any just to see runtime behaviour:
const z = new (x.constructor as any)
console.log(z)
```

No doubt there's a perfectly good type-related reason, but I can't see what it is.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the [constructor property](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L100) of all `Object`s is `Function`:

```
interface Object {
    /** The initial value of Object.prototype.constructor is the standard built-in Object constructor. */
    constructor: Function;
    ...
}
```

So you have to cast it, but you can cast it to something more meaningful than `any`:

```
type XConstructor = {
    new (): X;
}
const z = new (x.constructor as XConstructor)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an existing [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3841) about this; you can read the discussion in there for why this isn't already done.  The gist of it seems to be that it makes [typing subclasses difficult](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3841#issuecomment-163350868) because the constructors of subclasses don't have to be subtypes of the constructors of base classes.

If you don't care about subclasses and you can control the class declaration (or merge into it), you can do this yourself on a per-class basis:

```
class X {
  ['constructor']: typeof X;
}    
const x = new X;
const z = new x.constructor() // okay now
```

or just do the casting as mentioned in @NitzanTomer's answer.

Good luck!